# How to add long title in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Consider the following example:

```
data(canada.cities, package = "maps")

viz <- ggplot(canada.cities, aes(long, lat)) +

borders(regions = "canada") +

coord_equal() +

geom_point(aes(text = name, size = pop), colour = "red", alpha = 1/2) +

ggtitle(paste("Average bill for 1 people \n", 

"Average bill for 2 people \n", 

"Average bill for 3 people \n",

"Average bill for 4 people", sep = "")) 

ggplotly(viz)
```

[image]

The title is appeared in one line and this is why it is getting cut-off.
What I want is:

```
Average bill for 1 people
Average bill for 2 people
Average bill for 3 people
Average bill for 4 people
```

in the title (in 4 lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTML tag br, i.e.,`"<br>"` in `ggtitle`

```
data(canada.cities, package = "maps")

viz <- ggplot(canada.cities, aes(long, lat)) +

  borders(regions = "canada") +

  coord_equal() +


  geom_point(aes(text = name, size = pop), colour = "red", alpha = 1/2) +

  ggtitle(paste("Average bill for 1 people \n", 

                "Average bill for 2 people \n", 

                "Average bill for 3 people \n",

                "Average bill for 4 people", sep = "<br>")) 

ggplotly(viz)
```

And output:
[image]

Comment: how to make it so that text do not overlap the plot area?

Comment: you can make use of the `expand` argument in `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous`, You can add something like that into the code above
 `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.05, 0.05)) + `
  `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.05, 0.05)) +`